# How to send large text (String) as response from a REST service to REST client in Java?

Tags: java, rest

I have a restful application, where I need to send text as response to REST client. Now the problem is that sometimes text could be huge nearly 100000 characters.

Can I send large data as normal, plain text?

How to send it through the network to my REST client?

Comment: A POST response has generally no size limitations so 100000 characters should not be a problem. There can, however, be a limitation due to the web server and/or implementation you use.

Comment: 100,000 characters of ASCII text is only 98kB (allow a bit more for unicode) - people transfer much larger chunks of data over the internet all the time (think video)

Comment: @MTCoster thank you soo much. That is a valid point

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information @TA  .It helped to proceed.

Comment: For HTTP connections I'd recommend [chuncked transfer encodings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), especially for larger payloads, as this allows you to send data to the client continiously and end the stream with a simple `0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [HTTP compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) by using `Accept-Encoding` request header and `Content-Encoding` response header:

```
GET /your-url HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

This will make the compression transparent for most REST API clients. GZIP should be handled out of the box by most client libraries plus it can be disabled by not setting `Accept-Encoding` header.

Comment: Note that compression over HTTPS can leave you vulnernable to BREACH attacks.